# Is the rel attribute usage compatible with all browsers and tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

Just to be sure it can be safely used with [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com) scripting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's part of the HTML 4.01 Specification and should only be used as an attribute of the `a` and `link` tag (see [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#adef-rel)). Within `a` and `link` tags, it's [well supported](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_link_rel.asp).

Answer (score 3):

According to [the HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/attributes.html), `rel` is only valid on `a` and `link` elements.

As browsers don't validate documents you can get away with using it on any element you like, but it won't be valid, and it will be semantically meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

You'd really need to expand on what you mean by "compatible with all browsers".  All browsers will be able to render a document containing `rel` attributes without barfing, even if they don't explicitly understand what it means.  However, if you want to know whether all major browsers would take an explicit *action* when they encounter a rel attribute, you'd need to specify what situation you're thinking of and what you hope the browsers would do.

As for being compatible with all tags - no, the rel attribute is only appropriate for `A` and `LINK` tags in HTML 4 (as per [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#h-12.1.2)).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store custom data, you're better off using custom attributes. If you prefix them with "data-" then they are valid html5 as well.

See: http://ajaxian.com/archives/embed-your-data-in-html-5