# Can the rel= attribute contain any string characters and still validate?

Tags: xhtml, attributes, doctype, strict, rel

I'm wondering because I want to store something other than pre-defined keywords that are typically assigned to rel... and I just wanted to know if this is valid XHTML Strict or not.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666979/is-the-rel-attribute-usage-compatible-with-all-browsers-and-tags

Comment: @Shog9 : that question+answer gives some informations about which tags support the `rel` attribute -- but there is nothing there about which values that attribute can take ;; and the answers are mostly about HTML, and not about XHTML.

Comment: @Pascal: you are correct, my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can say, in the DTD *(can be downloaded [from here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Strict))* :

The `<link>` tag is defined as :

```
<!ELEMENT link EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST link
  %attrs;
  charset     %Charset;      #IMPLIED
  href        %URI;          #IMPLIED
  hreflang    %LanguageCode; #IMPLIED
  type        %ContentType;  #IMPLIED
  rel         %LinkTypes;    #IMPLIED
  rev         %LinkTypes;    #IMPLIED
  media       %MediaDesc;    #IMPLIED
  >
```

So, the `rel` is defined as `%LinkTypes;`.

Same for the `<a>` tag :

```
<!ELEMENT a %a.content;>
<!ATTLIST a
  %attrs;
  %focus;
  charset     %Charset;      #IMPLIED
  type        %ContentType;  #IMPLIED
  name        NMTOKEN        #IMPLIED
  href        %URI;          #IMPLIED
  hreflang    %LanguageCode; #IMPLIED
  rel         %LinkTypes;    #IMPLIED
  rev         %LinkTypes;    #IMPLIED
  shape       %Shape;        "rect"
  coords      %Coords;       #IMPLIED
  >
```

And the entity `LinkTypes` is defined as :

```
<!ENTITY % LinkTypes "CDATA">
    <!-- space-separated list of link types -->
```

So, trying to make things short :

- The `rel` attribute is supported, but only for `<a>` and `<link>` tags
- The `rel` attribute can contain `CDATA` -- i.e. it's not restricted to a specific list of words.

Comment: I'm trying to to the same the next question is, is this a good practice? save data in the rel attribute??